# Graphics Device initialization failed for : es2, sw Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java --module-path /Users/ousmanedia/Downloads/javafx-sdk-17.0.10/lib --add-modules javafx.controls -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar /Users/ousmanedia/Desktop/Etudes/semestre_4/interfaceGraphique/TP1-dia47u/testIG/out/artifacts/testIG_jar/testIG.jar
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:253)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:268)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:410)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1082)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1082)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:280)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:410)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
... 5 more

Process finished with exit code 1

Hello !
Can some one help ? I want to run my testApp.jar after doing the configuration but I got this bug since yesterday.
I work on IntelliJ , on Mac OS